# Database level migrations in parse server

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, parse-server

Is there a possible way of writing database migrations for `Parse Server`?

My use case is: I want some tables with pre-populated data whenever I connect my application to a fresh `mongodb server`. Say for example, setup a staging environment, setup a local development environment etc etc.
I could not really find anything in the docs.

Am i going in the right direction or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the Parse.com -> Parse-Server migration is that you now have to manage your own database.  Parse-Server gives you the necessary tools to connect to your database, but you have to do things like manage indexes (mlab gives you weekly tips on what indexes you could add for improvement!), uploading large amounts of data, etc.

So, if your question is "Does Parse-Server do this?"  No, and they won't.

If your question is "Can this be done?" Well, yes!  MongoDB has an upload feature that takes in JSON or CSV, if I recall correctly. I know you can upload a collection, I'm not sure if you can do multiple collections at a time.  One caveat is that you need to set createdAt and updatedAt and objectId yourself for this, but yes you can do this.

If you aren't too familiar with working with raw data that mongo needs, you could always setup the tables you want if they aren't too big, export all the data, and then use that data export as the import for all the fresh databases thereafter. Only issue there is that updatedAt and createdAt will show old dates on new instances.

Comment: thanks Jake, I'd rather write database migrations. but the real problem I am foreseeing is  for collections like that of _Role, _User, you won't want to export data everytime you deploy to a new server. and thats not the preferred way anyway.

Comment: Why do you have to export every time you deploy? You can export individual collections, so if you specifically want _Role, you can only get _Role. You can put together a bash script that does the importing for all the new mongo instances. You can also keep a master copy of the fresh db collections, so it's always the same each time you start.  If you were worried about the created and updated at times, you could even have the script replace all those with the current date time.